# How to I tell Jenkinsfile to use ssh instead of http for checkedout code?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

It seems that the code checkout using Jenkinsfile is using http for the remote origin and we do want to use ssh instead.

```
#!groovy

stage 'build'
node {
    checkout scm
    sh "cat .git/config"
}
```

This will output a https origin instead of a ssh one. The job is configured using github-organization-pipeline plugin, so there is no way to control the source from the job configuration in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current approach, which is ugly, I am not going to defend that.

```
tokens = "${env.JOB_NAME}".tokenize('/')
org = tokens[0]
repo = tokens[1]
branch = tokens[2]
sh "git remote set-url origin git@github.com:${org}/${repo}.git"
```

This works because github-organization-plugin generate jobs names that look like `org/repo/branch`.

Answer (score 0):

The organization folder’s configuration screen has an option to use specific checkout credentials, typically an SSH private key. By default it uses the API scan credentials, typically an access token which can be used for HTTPS checkouts (GitHub’s own recommendation).

Comment: Just for further detail for the multibranch pipeline plugin, the checkout credentials can be set after expanding the `Advanced` section of branch source.  If set to an ssh key credential it will use ssh.